# Dxscene and VGscene with Delphi

Tags: wpf, delphi, replace

I am using delphi as my primary development tool. 
and recently I found these 2 libraries in [KSDEV.com](http://ksdev.com)

and i found they are similar to WPF . So i just downloaded them and stated to playing with them  until the time to end comes ( i have not checked its license policies yet). I am not a good WPF knowledge person but i found was WPF hard to develop.

But my doubt is , are these 2 libraries can replace WPF in delphi . what are the drawbacks Dxscene and VGscene have or  what are the drawbacks WPF have ,

There are only a little articles about them in internet (google gave me millions of results but most of them repeated 2 articles  which was published in KSDEV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VGScene and DXScene can be compaired to WPF for the rendering result.

I think VG/DXScene are less resource consuming, and what I like against WPF, is that they are not XML-based. 
You use regular Delphi components to define your UI.

But the learning curve and the documentation is still a bit lacking for VX/DXScene.
I found out to be a bit difficult to create forms with DXScene. VXScene is perhaps a bit easier to create your UI with the mouse.

I think the full power of these libraries will be obtained using code-generated UI.

I don't like the XML root of WPF. It's verbose, and difficult to work with, with real application with a lot of forms. For some projects, the external WPF designer could be necessary.

But don't ask Microsoft why they don't publish WPF-based applications... and they still use unmanaged code...

Answer (score 1):

VgScene and DxScene are really cool libraries! You can make fast and nice looking GUI's with all kind of effects. It also has a grid component now!

But when I tried using them, I encountered some "drawbacks": there is little documentation how to make and what to use for a complex GUI (there are some nice demo's for simple GUI's though). So it has a relative high learning curve (when you only have VCL knowlegde because it is very different).

But besides these things, I think it is worth trying (only if you know how to do it and/or spend some time learning). It has good platform support (via FPC and OpenGL) so you can run it also on MacOs, Linux and iPhone/iPad!

Answer (score 0):

Since they do not depend on WPF, they can be used for cross platform development in Lazarus/[CodeTyphon](http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&Itemid=148). That is the main advantage for me. Drawback is documentation.